# Highcharts range line

Tags: highcharts, range, lines

We currently are looking for some help in getting solid range lines to appear longitudinally on our charts.

For example: Test A has a range of 0 (Very low), 3 (Moderately low), 5 (Low), 5 to 7 (Normal), 7+ (High), 9+ (Moderately high), and 11+ (Very high).

We're looking for a Red line in the Very high condition, Orange in Moderately high, and Yellow for high. Between the normal range we're looking for a Green line at the upper and lower boundary (between 5 and 7).

I don't have any code to show, but I wanted to make sure that Highcharts was even capable of this. I've attached an image of what I'm looking for. If it is possible and you have an example of some code, please let me know.

[image: mocked up range lines on a current pH chart]

Comment: You can do this with **plotLines** : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines

Comment: Marvin thank you for your answer! You just made my day!